# Slamdata Error when using variable in 3 level chained markdown : There is no binding for the variable

Tags: markdown, chained, slamdata

Slamdata Vesion : 4.1.1 
There are 3 decks.
Each has set up markdown and show markdown cards used in it.

Variables set in  deck 1 accessible and working fine in deck 2 
(a mirror of deck 1)

Additional variable created in deck 2 .
Show markdown card shows data correctly for this additional variable in deck 2.
But gives error below mentioned when trying to use this variable for creating another markdown in deck 3 ( a mirror of deck 2) :

"There is no binding for the variable"